# i want to clear all messages on a telegram group with python telegram bot (Clear history)

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

i want to clear all messages on a telegram group with python telegram bot

or Clear History

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the last message's id (e.g. when the user sends the `/clear` command you read the `message_id` of the message just sent) and then create a for loop that start from 0 (the first message in that group) and count up to the last message's id and for each cycle use the [deleteMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage) method to delete the corrisponding message. Set the parameter `message_id` to the cycle count of the loop (the messages in a group are incremental 1, 2, 3...).

Comment: ok. But this can be very time consuming .Is there a way to clear history altogether?

Comment: No, I don't think so